# MSAL - 'AADSTS50148: The code_verifier does not match the code_challenge supplied in the authorization request for PKCE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

i am currently working into implementing MSAL in my application for user validation against the AD, however i am getting this error
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: 'AADSTS50148: The code_verifier does not match the code_challenge supplied in the authorization request for PKCE.

i am currently making the Login post to retrieve the access code and it is working fine, however when i try to exchange that code for a token to retrieve the user information i get the error stated above
my current logic is the following

```
 [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
        {

           
            var azureAdAuthority = msalHelper.msalConfig.Authority;
            var azureAdClientId = msalHelper.msalConfig.ClientId;
            var redirectUri = msalHelper.msalConfig.RedirectUri;
            var scope = "openid profile email"; 

            
            var state = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            
            string codeVerifier = MSALHelper.GenerateCodeVerifier();
            string codeChallenge = MSALHelper.GenerateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier);
            Session["CodeVerifier"] = codeVerifier;
            
            var authorizationUri = $"{azureAdAuthority}/oauth2/authorize" +
                $"?client_id={azureAdClientId}" +
                $"&response_type=code" +
                $"&redirect_uri={redirectUri}" +
                $"&scope={scope}" +
                $"&state={state}" +
                $"&code_challenge_method=S256" + // PKCE method
                $"&code_challenge={codeChallenge}";

            
            return Redirect(authorizationUri);
        }


        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Callback(string code, string state)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
            {
                
                return View("Error");
            }

            try
            {
                
                var azureAdAuthority = msalHelper.msalConfig.Authority;
                var azureAdClientId = msalHelper.msalConfig.ClientId;
                var azureAdClientSecret = msalHelper.msalConfig.ClientSecret;
                var redirectUri = msalHelper.msalConfig.RedirectUri;

                var confidentialClientApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                    .Create(azureAdClientId)
                    .WithAuthority(azureAdAuthority)
                    .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                    .WithClientSecret(azureAdClientSecret)
                    .Build();

                string codeVerifier = HttpContext.Session["CodeVerifier"].ToString();
                var extraQueryParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "code_verifier", codeVerifier },
                    {"grant_type", "authorization_code"}
                };
               
                var result = await confidentialClientApp
                    .AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                        new[] { "email" },
                        code
                    ).WithExtraQueryParameters(extraQueryParameters)
                    .ExecuteAsync();

                var accessToken = result.AccessToken;
                var idToken = result.IdToken;
                var username = result.Account.Username;


                return RedirectToAction("Success");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
```

Also here are my methods to generate the code challenge and verifiers

```
       public static string GenerateCodeVerifier(uint size = 128)
        {
            if (size < 43 || size > 128)
                size = 128;

            const string unreservedCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~";
            Random random = new Random();
            char[] highEntropyCryptograph = new char[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < highEntropyCryptograph.Length; i++)
            {
                highEntropyCryptograph[i] = unreservedCharacters[random.Next(unreservedCharacters.Length)];
            }

            return new string(highEntropyCryptograph);
        }
        public static string GenerateCodeChallenge(string codeVerifier)
        {
            using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
            {
                var challengeBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(codeVerifier));
                return Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(challengeBytes);
            }
        }
```

Please do let me know if there is anything else i should provide, is my first time doing a question in the forum, thanks!

Based on my requirements i am not setting up msal on the startup of the application since all the settings change dinamically from the login page based on the agency they selected (to point other AD)
i've tried several different structures and logic for implementing this, and this is as far as i've got, please do let me know if my code is not secure enough or i am doing something wrong, i did research a lot in to this issue, tried different code snippets but am still getting the same error